# Internal communication among services with app mesh in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, envoyproxy, aws-app-mesh

I have application stack consisting of three services in AWS ECS. I have been planning to implement service mesh using AWS App Mesh. I have followed the following instructions to setup the mTLS for my services.
https://awscloudfeed.com/whats-new/security/how-to-use-acm-private-ca-for-enabling-mtls-in-aws-app-mesh

Using the technique mentioned on the blog I was able to setup the mTLS and communication is working fine from virtual gateway to services.

But when one of the service tries to access another service it fails to make connection. Services are built using NodeJS and one service(let's say A) use request library to call service B. From my understanding of the service mesh, the TLS session initiation should start from the envoy proxy of Service A and terminate in the envoy proxy of Service B. In this case I should have used the service discovery url of the Service B (eg. http://serviceb.example.com) when calling it from the serivce A. While doing so, I get ECONNRESET error with message socket hangup. And while using https protocol (eg https://serviceb.example.com) I get ECONNRESET error with message of TLS error.

But if I disable the client certificate requirement for the service B, I am able to access it from service A with https protocol. Does this mean that if i need to set the mtls in appmesh, i will need to load the client certificate through the application itself? I think the request should have gone through without issue as client certificate is provided through the backed client configuration.

Can you help me understand how app mesh mTLS work and if I am missing something while configuring the app mesh?
Thank You

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you'd need TLS termination on a virtual node?

Comment: Envoy should be handling all the SSL on-loading. Make sure you have configured all the security groups properly (e.g. allowing port 443); having the correct permissions (e.g. AWSServiceRoleForAppMesh) and in case you use a custom cert (acm-pa), also add permissions to these, "acm:ExportCertificate", "acm:DescribeCertificate"